# How to remove the vertical border between windows in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I remove the border between windows? I'm using Emacs with `-nw`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The border is drawn in vertical-border-face, so you could customize that to match your background color:

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html
```

It won't be completly removed, but you won't be able to see it with the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks! `vertical-border` was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To "remove" the vertical bar characters (`|`) in terminal Emacs, you could make them have the same color as their background. This effectively makes them invisible. Add this to your Emacs configuration file:

```lisp
(set-face-foreground 'vertical-border
                     (face-background 'vertical-border nil t))
```

Before:
[image: Emacs vertical border]
After:
[image: Emacs invisible vertical boder]